# PredicateBuilder Contains breaks when value is null

Tags: c#, ef-core-2.2, linqkit

It appears that my LinqKit Predicatebuilder function breaks when either the FirstName or LastName value = null.

```cs
public partial class Student
{
    public int id { get; set; } // PK
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

private Expression<Func<Student, bool>> BuildDynamicWhereClause(string searchValue)
{
    // simple method to dynamically plugin a where clause
    var predicate = PredicateBuilder.New<Student>(true); // true -where(true) return all

    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchValue) == false)
    {
        var searchTerms = searchValue.Split(' ').ToList().ConvertAll(x => x.ToLower());

        predicate = predicate.Or(s => searchTerms.Any(srch => s.FirstName.Contains(srch)));
        predicate = predicate.Or(s => searchTerms.Any(srch => s.LastName.Contains(srch)));
    }
    return predicate;
}
```

How do I rewrite `predicate.Or(s => searchTerms.Any(srch => s.FirstName.Contains(srch)));` since Contains requires a value to search and throws an exception?

I've tried:

```cs
predicate = predicate.Or(s => searchTerms.Any(srch => s.FirstName == null ? false : s.FirstName.Contains(srch)));
```

and also

```cs
predicate = predicate.Or(s => searchTerms.Any(srch => s.FirstName == null ? true : s.FirstName.Contains(srch)));
```

which compiles but now the FirstName is not searched.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [null conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-).  This code only calls `Contains` if `FirstName` is not null, avoiding the exception.

```
searchTerms.Any(srch => s.FirstName?.Contains(srch) == true));
```

The explicit `== true` is necessary as this evaluates to a `bool?` and not a `bool`.

For LINQ providers that don't support this operator it's effectively the same as

```
searchTerms.Any(srch => s.FirstName == null ? false : s.FirstName.Contains(srch));
```